# Issue with passing parameters to net user command in powershell

Tags: powershell

I need to pass in PowerShell the list of local users:

```
users$=@(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter  "LocalAccount='True'" 
| select-object -property name 
| ft -hidetableheaders)
```

to the command `foreach ($i in $users){net user $i)`

But it does not work, although it should.

As I can see the length of array is $users.length 1 item for my case.

```
PS C:\> $users.length
1
```

Although in `echo $users`, the list contains only 3 items as I can see see it visually: 1, Administrator, Guest.

Comment: Shouldn't it be `$users=@(Get-WmiObject .. ` ? And also the loop: `foreach ($i in $users){net user $i } ` like this? I changed the dollar sign before the variable and the last curly bracket.

Comment: Try to replace `select-object -property name | ft -hidetableheaders` with `select-object -expandproperty name`.

Answer (score -1):

Try to replace `select-object -property name | ft -hidetableheaders` with `select-object -expandproperty name`.

**Explanation**:

1. FT (Format-Table) returns not a string array, but an array of objects. You could check it by using `$users | Get-Member` - you will see something like this:

   ```
   $users | gm

   TypeName: Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.Internal.Format.FormatStartData
   ...
   ```
2. `select -property name` will return you a hashtable, not a string as well. So you need to replace it with `-ExpandProperty` to return a string value.

This is your working construction:

```
$users = @(Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserAccount -Filter "LocalAccount='True'" | 
    Select-Object -ExpandProperty name)


foreach ($i in $users) {
    & net user $i
}
```

---

P.S. btw, Костя, ты в курсе про [русский StackOverflow](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/)? :) Just in case...